# How to delete all register from an m:n association table in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models with a `m:n` association through a table, and I want to delete all the association between this 2 models.
To add an association I can do this:

```
//just for example, imagine that a1, b1 and b2 are instances of models A and B
//and they association are made through table AB
a1.addB(b1);  
a1.addB(b2);
// or
a1.setB([b1,b2]);
```

Now I have a register in table AB that associate the `a1` to `b1`, and another that associate `a1` to `b2`.

My problem is: How can I remove all associations between `a1` and `B` registers, in table `AB` ?
I don't want to delete de `a1` register, just disassociate it from `B`.

I try to do this:

```
a1.set();
```

But it try to insert a `NULL` value in table `AB`

UPDATE: There is an [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6095) on `Sequelize` about that

Comment: Does `a1.removeB(b1); ` work?

Comment: @doublesharp this remove the register that associate `b1` with `a1`. What I want is to remove all associations from `a1`... I know that I can query all the associations, and than remove it, but I want to know if it has a better way to do that.. like something: `a1.removeAllB()`

Comment: If you want to do it in a single query your best option might be a raw SQL query, I'm not aware of a way to do it with Sequelize's sugar.

Comment: One other option would be to write an `instanceMethod` that does this for you, taking a `Model` as the argument. Could possibly be useful to contribute back to the project.

Comment: Any update on that or a workaround? im looking for the exact same thing